# Getting exception Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x83\x93 in C# code

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, unicode, mariadb, ado.net

I am reading text file in C# code and saving it into maria db.
I have column type of "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" but still it throws below exception.

> Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x83\x93 19...' for column `.`.`v_desc` at row 247

To remove this error, I have added the code `readText.Replace("\xFFFD", "")`. For few
text files it works but for few text files it still gives error. Also replace method replaces the " ' " with empty. While reading this text on the web it not looks good.

Below is complete code.

```
dbfactory.AddInParam("desc", SqlType.VarChar, readText.Replace("\xFFFD", ""));
dbfactory.RunProc("sp name", out object returnValue);
```

Comment: Is there also a `SqlType.NVarChar` ?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing [Yes there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=net-7.0#fields)

Comment: @DavidG that's SqlDbType (sqlserver specific), not SqlType (apparently mariadb / mysql)